# facebook google oauth Uncaught exception

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

I integrated both google and facebook oauth in my application .
First I initiated the class for google like this

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("urmk google login");         
$oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
  return;
}
```

Google login process is working fine and i am able to get user info too. But 
Then I integrated facebook oauth

```
          FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET');
          $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://example.com/');
          $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
          try {
            $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
          } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
            // When Facebook returns an error
          } catch(\Exception $ex) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
          }
          if ($session) {
            // Logged in
            $user = $facebook->getUser();
            if ($user) {
              try {
                  $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
              } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                  error_log($e);
                  $user = null;
              }
          }

            if ($user) {
              $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
            } else {
              $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
            }

          }
```

It successfully takes me to user account where it ask for the user permission, but while redirecting to my SITE it throws an error saying

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message 
  'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'' in
  C:\xampp\htdocs\urmk\lib\src\auth\Google_OAuth2.php:113 Stack trace:
  #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\urmk\lib\src\Google_Client.php(131): 
  Google_OAuth2->authenticate(Array, 'AQASSzhhLhYIYxI...') #1 
  C:\xampp\htdocs\urmk\index.php(66):   
  Google_Client->authenticate('AQASSzhhLhYIYxI...') #2 {main} thrown in 
  C:\xampp\htdocs\urmk\lib\src\auth\Google_OAuth2.php on line 113**
```

And again if i change the **if (isset($_GET['code']))**    to                  **if (isset($_GET['something else']))** . It works fine. So how to resolve this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Phase I: Catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you have parameters in the 'authenticate' function call. From what I saw in the Google code for 'Google_OAuth2.php', it calls it itself. You will need to make sure that you set the variables. Check out the code below.

Also make sure you are using the correct version of the Google code... Online vs. Installed. I read that Installed version is Native.

```
if(isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

You can set the access token by...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}
```

If all else fails then read this document...
http://25labs.com/tutorial-implementing-google-api-using-oauth-2-0-in-php/

Also, catch the exception so you can at least get one or the other as a successful authentication rather than erroring out all together.